# El Capitan Fat32 partition problem

Tags: macos, partition, fat32

I have a strange problem in El Capitan.

I have a second internal drive which is divided into two partitions: one Fat32 and one HFS+ Journaled.

I do not see this drive in console when I type `diskutil list /`, but I can see the HFS+ partition in the system and I can use it. I do not see Fat32 partition.

May it be a permission problem? If yes, how can it be fixed right now? Disk Utility is not supporting this option anymore. I do not have Windows installed.

Comment: FAT32 disks do not support permissions and Disk Utility never offered Verify Disk Permissions on them anyway.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show what `diskutil list` shows for the disk in question? if it's the boot disk, use `diskutil list disk0` - but since it's the second you might need 1 or 2 added to show us the overall idea of what's happening / won't show you anything helpful as your question initially reads...

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `diskutil list /` in Terminal only partitions of the boot device are visible.

The proper command to enter is just `diskutil list`.

With the disk identifier diskX found above try to verify the disk and the volume:

```
diskutil verifyDisk /dev/diskX
diskutil verifyVolume /dev/diskXsY
```

If verification was successful try to make a mountpoint:

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/EXT_HD_FAT32
```

and try to mount the partition there:

```
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/diskXsY /Volumes/EXT_HD_FAT32/
```